# iOS MDM Centralized, Managed and Enforced Device Backup

Tags: backup, iphone, mdm

I am not entirely sure that such a solution exists due to limitations imposed by Apple's iOS security and sandboxing implementations in iOS. Nonetheless, I have a client that has a fleet of company owned iOS Devices. The devices are enrolled in mobile profiles via Apple's Profile Manager prior to distribution. The users are permitted to use these devices for corporate and personal consumption.

The client is looking for an automated solution to centralize and enforce "whole device backup." Their expectations is that they should be able to enforce the backup of all devices (in the same style that an iOS device would backup via iTunes or iCloud) but to a centralized location in-house or cloud.

The primary reasons are:

- Recoverability: employee loses device, IT would be able to restore from last backup
- Archiving/Reference: terminated employees backup could be restored to examine message and other device data for reference

I have looked at several software solutions that can backup data for corporate developed apps but nothing that does whole device backup.

How do organizations deal with the recoverability and archiving scenarios listed above? Or am I just thinking about the problem from the wrong angle?